# Fedora vs. Ubuntu installation

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, install, boot

I am using Fedora 13, and it was my friend who did the installation for me. I have used Ubuntu also and I found it more easy to install than fedora. Ubuntu uses a WUBI installer (if I am correct) and its more easy for the users to install and remove Ubuntu. For a person who knows how to install and remove an application in Windows, can they install/remove Ubuntu also.

Why is it that its not the same with Fedora. Are there any steps being taken for making it more user-friendly.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't only have a wubi installer; there are other ways of installing it too. In fact, using the wubi installer ends up installing Ubuntu to an existing Windows partition. That way you are stuck with the inferior filesystems like FAT-32, rather than making full use of something like EXT4. This may be "easier", but it's technically inferior. Even if I were using Ubuntu I wouldn't use the Wubi installer.

Comment: I down-voted this becuase I think it is too argumentative.  For instance, I find that the Fedora installer is much easier to use than the Ubuntu installer depending on your needs.  I often use LVM (a way to manage disk space that can abstract from individual disks), which the standard Ubuntu installer doesn't even support and is very user-unfriendly in the alternate installer.

Comment: @Steven D: Note the OP's "(if I am correct)". It isn't argumentative, it is admittedly ignorant of the alternatives, which is why we're here, to patch our collective ignorances. That oughtn't be penalized (but thanks for explaining why).

Comment: Good point. Down vote removed. Edit: Gah!  For some reason it won't allow me to remove my down vote.

Comment: I added the tag "boot" which may unlock the downvote, but I wouldn't worry about it much.

Comment: @Steven Votes are [locked in](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/if-you-just-witnessed-tactical-downvoting-is-it-a-reportable-offense/18046#18046) after five minutes to help prevent strategic downvoting. msw is right, now that the post has been edited you can retract your vote

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the information.  @msw: Thanks for editing. Vote removed.

Comment: Someone forgot to mention that Fedora is Red Hat based, and as such it uses .rpm packages, while Ubuntu is Debian-based, and as such uses Debian's package format (.pkg files).

Comment: Fedora's not so much based on Red Hat anymore. Originally, it was just a continuation of the older Red Hat Linux OS, but now they do their own thing and occasionally RHEL swipes ideas from them if the ideas seem to work.

Comment: … you mean .deb files, right?

Comment: Albeit, but you are missing my point. My point is that Fedora can't use Debian packages while Ubuntu or Debian can't use Red-Hat packages.

Comment: Yes, .deb files.

Comment: I can't figure out what the package format has to do with Fedora's ease of distro installation

Comment: @MichaelMrozek the package format has ease to do with it. Apt-Get is generally more simpler than installing an rpm, and if you wish to get an rpm for Debian or Ubuntu, there's a program to convert .rpm to .deb.

Comment: @ThomasStreiff But we're not talking about installing packages; the question is about installing the distro -- it wants to know why installing Ubuntu is harder than installing Fedora. Not installing packages under those distros

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the significant (including Fedora and Ubuntu) distributions prefer to install from a boot cd-rom or usb-stick these days. Windows need not part of the process at all.

[Wubi](http://wubi-installer.org/) is a windows application that can run Linux from a Windows file pretending to be a boot disk. Its purpose is to be have zero-impact on the Windows system:

> You keep Windows as it is, Wubi only
>   adds an extra option to boot into
>   Ubuntu. Wubi does not require you to
>   modify the partitions of your PC, or
>   to use a different bootloader, and
>   does not install special drivers. It
>   works just like any other application.

The [Fedora LiveCD](http://fedoraproject.org/get-fedora) and [Ubuntu LiveCD](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download) and even the tiny [DSL LiveCD](http://damnsmalllinux.org/) are the simplest installation methods.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu install will be basically boot from live cd/usb stick, click through some GUI screens and you are done.

Only thing to mind is the partitioning which if you want a clean install without dual booting or dual boot with windows is trivial.  (If you already have windows installed.)

In fact, I just did a f13 install the other day and it was eerily similar to ubuntu installs.